# MATLAB GUI Collides when using big matrices

Tags: matlab, user-interface, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

[image: Collided Matlab GUI]

I don't know what causes this but I get this kind of window when I am working with big matrices.

After I switch to the different window and come back to Matlab GUI again, it disappears. However, if I scroll down on the GUI, I get the same collided window again...

P.S. I am using Matlab R2015a on Ubuntu 16.04

Edit: The matrices' dimension was around 16000x30

Comment: Can you give some information about the data format and the matrix dimensions?

Comment: The matrices' dimension was around 16000x30

Comment: That's not a big matrix, worse case scenario its about 4Mb of Data.... I'd say its a bug, I had weird things  happening with MATLAB Ubuntu in the past, mainly with the GUI, as its java based and works weird in Ubuntu (or so I read somewhere in the interwebz)

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  Try submitting a ticket to MathWorks.